# How to pull in values from 2nd row (for a specific field) into the 1st row for a given name?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table such as the one below (table1), and I am trying to write a query that shows only the 1st rows for each name, but those rows have a null for the title, so I want to pull in their titles from the immediate next row.

table1

| Name | Title | Row |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dan | NULL | 1 |
| Dan | Engineer | 2 |
| Dan | Developer | 3 |
| Jay | NULL | 1 |
| Jay | Lawyer | 2 |

The final result should look like the following:

| Name | Title | Row |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dan | Engineer | 1 |
| Jay | Lawyer | 1 |

I've only written this so far, I don't know how to pull in the titles from the previous row. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
select *
from table1
where Row = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select 
  Name, 
  max(Title) over(partition by Name) as Title, 
  Row 
from table1 
qualify Row = 2
```

Is probably one of the quickest way to get your result. But it doesn't take properly into account if a name has multiple titles, or if the number of row can vary from person to person.

```sql
select 
  Name, 
  last_value(Title ignore nulls) over(partition by Name order by Row asc) as Title, 
  Row 
from table1 
qualify row_number() over(partition by Name order by Row desc) = 1
```

Is more appropriate to take into account those cases

Edit:

```sql
select 
  Name,
  string_agg(Title order by Row limit 1) as Title,
  min(Row) as Row
from table1
group by Name
```

[image]

Comment: You're right, good call. I changed the example in my question so it more accurately reflects my needs.

Comment: I couldn't get your solution to work

Comment: How so? With the new result example it would indeed require a different approach since the main final row is different. Depending on the amount of fields, the new edit could also be a solution

Comment: The titles are still null, with all 3 methods

Comment: Then there must be something differing between your source table and what you provided. I added a screenshot of the result I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, IFNULL(Title, LeadTitle), Row
FROM (
  SELECT Name, Title, LEAD(Title) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ROW) AS LeadTitle, Row
  FROM `dataset.tablename` )
WHERE Row = 1
```